# uploading item to multiple locations creates duplicates

Tags: square-connect

I am currently using v1 api to upload items to square. For example, the sample item post below is sent to 2 locations. When posting I get an HTTP response "OK", but when I go to the square website to verify that all items were uploaded correctly I see an item per location. This is causing a problem because now I can't modify the item on the square website because it says there are duplicate SKUs.

Then I use the API to get the item information thinking that maybe I would find something there, but the JSON looks exactly the same for both locations.

API documentation: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#post-items

URL: POST  /v1/{location_id}/items/

JSON:

```
{
    "fees": [],
    "variations": [
      {
        "inventory_alert_type": "NONE",
        "track_inventory": false,
        "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
        "id": "0BBF12F9-1347-11E4-A55E-000C293C8BE4_VID",
        "name": "(Pound)",
        "price_money": {
          "currency_code": "USD",
          "amount": 699
        },
        "sku": "6210067002",
        "ordinal": 1,
        "item_id": "0BBF12F9-1347-11E4-A55E-000C293C8BE4_PID"
      }
    ],
    "available_for_pickup": true,
    "available_online": true,
    "visibility": "PRIVATE",
    "id": "0BBF12F9-1347-11E4-A55E-000C293C8BE4_PID",
    "description": "",
    "name": "Baby Swiss",
    "abbreviation": "",
    "type": "NORMAL"
}
```

You can see from the picture below that the item shows up twice. I would post more pictures, but since this is my first post stack overflow is telling me I need more reputation.

[Duplicate Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghIkF.png)

What am I doing wrong? Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, that is the expected functionality for the API. New items made with the v1 inventory API can only be associated with one location.